.NET Aspire doesn't replace http client Uri with actual address in blazor webassembly standalone app in .net 8
i referenced the blazor project to Aspire app host so this is my aspire app host code
using AnswerMe.Aspire.AppHost;

var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var identityServerDb=builder.AddPostgres("identityserver", password: builder.CreateStablePassword("AnswerMeDB-password"))
    .WithDataVolume()
    .WithPgAdmin()
    .AddDatabase("IdentityServerDb");

var identityServerApi = builder.AddProject<Projects.IdentityServer_Api>("identityserverapi")
    .WithReference(identityServerDb);

var client = builder.AddProject<Projects.AnswerMe_Client>("answermeclient")
    .WithReference(identityServerApi);

builder. Build().Run();

and this is my blazor code to add HTTP client
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(nameof(HttpClients.IdentityServer),
    client => { client.BaseAddress = new("http://identityserverapi"); });

so as you can see in the result it doesn't replace the http://identityserverapi with the actual address

and also i found the builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("identityserverapi"); doesn't work because we don't have appsettings.json in blazor wasm so I think Aspire doesn't work fo the blazor wasm

can you provide your github repo if possible ?

Just as a point of interest, you can have appSettings.json in Blazor WASM. It goes in the /wwwroot directory. I'm still interested in your question though. I hope somebody posts an answer.
